# Client side validation suddenly doesn't work on property with the same name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have these class

```
public class ItemType
{
    public ItemType()
    {
        SubItems = new List<SubItem>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Hidden { get; set; }
    [NonPersistent]
    public List<SubItem> SubItems { get; set; }
}

public class ItemTypeValidator : AbstractValidator<ItemType>
{
    public ItemTypeValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().Length(1, 255);
        RuleForEach(x => x.SubItems).SetValidator(new SubItemValidator());
    }
}

public class SubItem
{
    public SubItem()
    {
        WorkLevels = new List<WorkLevel>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool ShowGender { get; set; }
    public int ItemTypeID { get; set; }
    [NonPersistent]
    public List<WorkLevel> WorkLevels { get; set; }
    [NonPersistent]
    public ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
}

public class SubItemValidator : AbstractValidator<SubItem>
{
    public SubItemValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().Length(1, 255);
        RuleForEach(x => x.WorkLevels).SetValidator(new WorkLevelValidator());
    }
}

    public class WorkLevel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int SubItemID { get; set; }
    [NonPersistent]
    public SubItem SubItem { get; set; }
}

public class WorkLevelValidator : AbstractValidator<WorkLevel>
{
    public WorkLevelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().Length(1, 255);
        RuleFor(x => x.Price).NotEmpty().LessThan(9999999999);
    }
}
```

Here's my View.

```
@model ItemType
...
...
<input asp-for="ID" type="hidden" class="form-control">
<input asp-for="Name" type="text" class="form-control">
<span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-red"></span>
...
...
@for (int x = 0; x < Model.SubItems.Count; x++)
{
    <input asp-for="SubItems[x].ID" type="hidden" class="form-control">
    <input asp-for="SubItems[x].Name" type="text" class="form-control">
    <span asp-validation-for="SubItems[x].Name" class="text-red"></span>

    @for (int y = 0; y < Model.SubItems[x].WorkLevels.Count; y++)
    {
        <input asp-for="SubItems[x].WorkLevels[y].ID" type="hidden" class="form-control">
        <input asp-for="SubItems[x].WorkLevels[y].Name" type="text" class="form-control">
        <span asp-validation-for="SubItems[x].WorkLevels[y].Name" class="text-red"></span>
    }
}
```

It works fine before, but without any changes somehow the `Name` property is no longer triggering Client Side validation (it still works fine on server side validation because `ModelState.IsValid` is always false).

[image]

Any idea why? Any help will be appreciated

EDIT: The HTML generated also seems okay

[image]

Comment: Can you please use git to show what has changed since when it didn't work, and now?

Comment: @mjwills: that's the thing, I didn't change anything except some other controller that doesn't have any relation with this menu